# Find Match between two uneven Variant arrays

Tags: excel, vba, match, variant-array

I need to check if each string in arr1 has a match in arr2.

If it has a match then write "Match" to the column next to arr1, if not then "Not Match".

Here's how my sheet looks:

[image: How my Sheet looks]

```
Sub Variant_Array_Question()
'Here is my frankenstein monster of a code
    Dim DocNm As Variant, NroNm As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim NroLastRow As Long, DocLastRow As Long

    'Arr1
    DocLastRow = ShStart.Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    DocNm = ShStart.Range("Q6:Q" & DocLastRow).Value

    'Arr2
    NroLastRow = ShStart.Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    NroNm = ShStart.Range("T6:T" & NroLastRow).Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(DocNm)
        For j = 1 To UBound(NroNm)
            If DocNm(i, 1) = NroNm(j, 1) Then
                'Match was found ==== Run into Problem here
                DocNm(i, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Match"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If i > UBound(NroNm) Then
            'No match was found ==== Run into Problem here
            DocNm(i, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Not Match"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DocNm(i, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Match"` has no meaning for an array. An array do not have an `Offset` property.

If your sheet example is real in terms of ranges size, use `Ranges` instead of arrays.

In order to use arrays and obtain the result you need you must use a third array. Dimension it as your first array Ubound, but I will better transform your code:

```
Sub Variant_Array_Question()
    Dim DocNm As Variant, NroNm As Variant, arrStat As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, boolFound As Boolean
    Dim NroLastRow As Long, DocLastRow As Long
    Dim ShStart As Worksheet
    Set ShStart = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet!!!
    'Arr1
    DocLastRow = ShStart.Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    DocNm = ShStart.Range("Q6:Q" & DocLastRow).value
    ReDim arrStat(1 To UBound(DocNm, 1), 1 To 1) 'arr 3
    'Arr2
    NroLastRow = ShStart.Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    NroNm = ShStart.Range("T6:T" & NroLastRow).value

    For i = 1 To UBound(DocNm)
        For j = 1 To UBound(NroNm)
            If DocNm(i, 1) = NroNm(j, 1) Then
                boolFound = True
                arrStat(i, 1) = "Match"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If Not boolFound Then
            arrStat(i, 1) = "Not Match"
        End If
        boolFound = False
    Next i
    ShStart.Range("R6").Resize(UBound(arrStat, 1), 1).value = arrStat
End Sub
```

Not tested, but I think it will work. If you would supply an editable example, I would test it...

Comment: Thanks FaneDuru! I tried it with the third array, but it didnt work so I erased it for this post. Guess I was on the right track. I'll give it another go and let you know what I come up with. Thanks again for answering in such a sort time!

Comment: I didn't see you had posted the code. I'm testing it right now though. Looks great!! I think this will solve it. I'll keep you posted, just a sec. =D

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that FaneDuru helped me solve. This goes for those noobs in need like me.

```
Sub Variant_Array_Response()
    Dim DocNm As Variant, NroNm As Variant, ResStatus As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, boolFound As Boolean
    Dim NroLastRow As Long, DocLastRow As Long
    Dim ShStart As Worksheet

    Set ShStart = ActiveSheet

    'Arr1
    DocLastRow = ShStart.Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    DocNm = ShStart.Range("Q6:Q" & DocLastRow).Value

    'Arr2
    NroLastRow = ShStart.Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    NroNm = ShStart.Range("T6:T" & NroLastRow).Value

    'Arr3
    'ResStatus = ShStart.Range("Q6:Q" & DocLastRow).Offset(, 1) 'What I had
    ReDim ResStatus(1 To UBound(DocNm, 1), 1 To 1) 'FaneDuru's pice

    For i = 1 To UBound(DocNm)
        For j = 1 To UBound(NroNm)
            If DocNm(i, 1) = NroNm(j, 1) Then
                boolFound = True
                ResStatus(i, 1) = "Match"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j

        If Not boolFound Then
            ResStatus(i, 1) = "Not Match"
        End If
        boolFound = False
    Next i
    ShStart.Range("R6").Resize(UBound(ResStatus, 1), 1).Value = ResStatus
End Sub
```